# using macros to place #ifdef in the code

Tags: c++, syntax, macros, syntax-error

I am trying to do something like this

```
#define VB_S #ifdef VERBOSE
#define VB_E #endif
```

so that in the code instead of writing

```
#ifdef VERBOSE
    cout << "XYZ" << endl;
#endif
```

I can write

```
VB_S  
    cout << "XYZ" << endl; 
VB_E
```

This gives me a compile time error: Stray '#' in the program.

Can anyone put light on what is the right way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#ifdef VERBOSE
#define VB(x) x
#else
#define VB(x) do { } while (false)
#endif


VB(cout << "foo");
```

Comment: Can x take any thing, e.g. I may have for loops that print a matrix

Comment: @Akhil: It won't be happy about anything with a , embedded - you could just make the for loop and use the macro to print, the compiler would likely optimize away a loop doing nothing if VERBOSE isn't defined.

Comment: Most of my prints are simple cout's. To be on the same side, I will use explicit ifdef's when I have for loops and the trick you gave for simpler statements. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Akhil: you can do simpler --> put the code of the loop into a function.

Answer (score 6):

You can't put directives inside macros. (`#` inside a macro as another signification -- it is the stringizing operator and must be followed by a parameter id -- but the restriction is older than that meaning)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Erik's response:

```
#ifdef VERBOSE
#define VB(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define VB(...) /* nothing */
#endif
```

Using a [variadic macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) has the benefit of allowing commas inside the `VB()` call.  Also, AFAIK, you can remove the `do`...`while`.

Comment: Unfortunately, though correct, `__VA_ARGS__` is not supported in C++03 (I am not sure about C++11).

Comment: Except both g++ and MSVC (the two most widely used compilers) both accept it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the following:

```
#define VERBOSE 1
// or 0, obviously

if (VERBOSE)
{
// Debug implementation
}
```

This is a little more readable since VB_S doesn't mean anything to the average user, but if (VERBOSE) does.

Comment: I like this one, VERBOSE can be used as a variable (instead of #define) and thus can be changed at run time through command-line arguments. No need to compile a VERBOSE and a NON-VERBSOE version.